# Transform variable to gamma distribution in R

Tags: r, gamma-distribution

I have a variable that I want to transform to a gamma distribution with known shape and rate parameters.  How can I transform the variable to a gamma distribution in R?  I've looked into the dgamma, pgamma, and qgamma functions, but I can't tell if any will do what I want.

Here's a small example:

```
variable <- rnorm(100)
shape <- .83
rate <- .01
```

Note: I realize this example uses normally distributed data (which doesn't fit a gamma distribution), but I need to rescale the variable to the original gamma distribution.

Comment: Have you tried simply generating data with a gamma dist, and parameters outlined?

Comment: I don't want to simulate the values from a gamma distribution, I want to transform/rescale a pre-existing variable to fit a gamma distribution with predefined parameters.  The pre-existing variable (unlike the example above) is not a vector of random numbers.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the distribution and quantile functions to translate:

```
qgamma(pnorm(variable), shape=.83, rate=.01)
```

This assumes that `variable` has mean 0, sd 1 (as it does for your example).  Otherwise you can pass the mean and sd into `pnorm`.

To see the transformation:

```
plot(density(variable))
```

[image]

```
plot(density(qgamma(pnorm(variable), shape=.83, rate=.01)))
```

[image]